# images larger than 56 kb appear broken after upgrade to wordpress 4.0

Tags: wordpress, filesize, broken-image

My site is lianavoinea.opa.ro. After I upload files larger than 56 kb I get the http error. If I refresh, I find that the image has been uploaded though. However, its thumbnail appears broken. Here a printscreen: http://lianavoinea.opa.ro/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/broken-thumbnails-worpress-4.0.png.
The problem is not caused by my host, because on another site on the same domain(agrobun.opa.ro) even if I get the http error, on refresh the thumbnail is not broken.
The file permission is not the problem, I checked in Filezilla and it is 755.
I would be very grateful if you could help me and I will not have to downgrade wordpress.
Thank you!!!

Comment: Plugin conflict? Memory issues? Could be a lot of things..

Comment: I have deactivated all plugins and it's not this. I don't have so many images. I don't have many themes installed (only the default from WordPress and my own). could you expand about memory issues? thanks a lot!